# Cast a C++ abstract class from a Python object derived from that C++ abstract class

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have been trying to cast an abstract class in a C++ program, trying different solution from this webpage and the official documentation, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772752/13522550)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011654/13522550), but nothing works.
My C++ abstract class is:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
    virtual void foo(){};
};
```

My wrapper to import to python is:

```
class BasePy: public Base 
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        PYBIND11_OVERLOAD_PURE(
                void, 
                Base, 
                foo);
    }
};
```

My import function and my import:

```
void import_base(pybind11::module m)
{
    using namespace pybind11;
    class_<Base, BasePy>(m, "Base")
        .def("foo", &Base::foo);
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(baselib, m)
{
    import_component(m);
}
```

I wrote a python class(derived.py):

```
import baselib

class test(baselib.Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10;

    def foo(self):
        print(self.x)
```

And finally my main:

```
scoped_interpreter guard{};
auto obj = module::import("derived").attr("test")(); 
// obj = {<pybind11::handle> = 
//         {<pybind11::detail::object_api<pybind11::handle>> = 
//           {<pybind11::detail::pyobject_tag> = 
//             {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>
//           }, 
//           m_ptr = 0x7ffff706f1d0 
//         }, 
//         <No data fields>}
Base* bas = isinstance<Base>(obj) ? (Base*)obj.cast<void*>() : nullptr;
// bas = (Base*) 0x0
```

"baselib.so" and the executable compiles as "derived.py" works on the python3 interpreter flawlessly.
In the interpreter:

```
derived.test.__base__ : <class 'baselib.base'>
derived.test.__class__ : <class 'pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type'>
derived.baselib == baselib : true
baselib.base.__base__ : <class 'pybind11_builtins.pybind11_object'>
baselib.base.__class__ : <class 'pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type'>
```

What am I failing to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! 
I find a solution, when I import the class I didn't add the init function of the trampoline class:

```
void import_base(pybind11::module m)
{
    using namespace pybind11;
    class_<Base,/*Holder*/ BasePy>(m, "Base")
    // You can add a holder like std::shared_ptr<Base> in "Holder"
        .def(init<>())// <--- THIS
        .def("foo", &Base::foo);
}
```

And in the python class we need to add the "abstract class initializer"(it is the trampoline initializer) like this:

```
class test(baselib.Base):
    def __init__(self):
        baselib.Base.__init__(self) // Adding this line
        self.x = 10;
```

And... Voilà! The problem is solved.